# How to publish/deploy a npm package to custom artifactory

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, artifactory, npm-package

I want to do something like this:

1. Create an npm package. Basically, a common code which I want to use for all of my projects. Which I created.
2. But now What I want is, Every time I commit something in git for this project, Jenkins should build it with updated alpha/beta version and should publish to my own artifactory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your Jenkins job can be configured to be triggered by a webhook, which would take care of the first part (every time I commit). Depending on which Git server you're using you can find a lot of tutorials how to do that:

- [For GitHub](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline)
- [For GitLab](https://jamalshahverdiev.wordpress.com/2018/02/07/jenkins-gitlab-integration-with-webhook/)
- [For Gogs](https://jamalshahverdiev.wordpress.com/2018/02/09/jenkins-gogs-integration-with-webhook/)

*please note this is just a random selection of tutorials how to set up the webhook triggers to work with Git servers and by no means an exhaustive list*

To publish your package to JFrog Artifactory you can either use the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin, or use the NPM command line. If you want to use the `npm` command line, you'll need to authenticate first:

```
# setting the default registry to Artifactory
npm config set registry http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo/
# log in
npm login
```

alternatively you can get a `.npmrc` file directly from Artifactory using:

```
curl -u admin:<CREDENTIAL> http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/artifactory/api/npm/auth
```

After that, there are two ways you can push your package to Artifactory:

- Edit your package.json file and add a publishConfig section to a local repository: `"publishConfig":{"registry":"http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo/"}`
- Provide a local repository to the npm publish command: `npm publish --registry http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo/`

Comment: which directory or files does npm-publish command upload to artifactory? how can I change those directories and files name or path in npm-publish command?